# How do I upgrade Android on my phone with Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, android, phone

I have a Galaxy Europa running Android v2.2. I want to upgrade it to Gingerbread v2.3. In Windows I would use Samsung Kies for this task. How do I do it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried installing Kies with Wine?

Comment: No, but isn't there some other way to do this (preferably without Kies)?

Comment: I would suggest installing Kies via Wine. Otherwise you can check out this thread on the xda site: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1156

Comment: @p00c Samsung Kies doesn't work in Wine....

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to download the firmware of Samsung Galaxy Europa Gingerbread from [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/?page=3&model=GT-I5500&pcode=0&os=1&type=1#firmware) , then install [Heimdall](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755265) to install the firmware onto your device. But make sure your phone is unlocked before doing so.

Comment: Isn't unlocking illegal in the States now?

Comment: @psryn Is the question limited to the States?

Comment: isn’t it illegal to unlock your phone? A. No, unlocking your phone is not the same as rooting it.. also unlocking any phone that you outright own is not illegal (in the US). Heimdall is the Odin equivalent in linux systems. plus one for using Heimdall.